# What are the drawbacks if we extend a class with MapActivity instead of Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an framework which is used overall the application, Which extends an activity, But in some scenario am using maps in my project, So i need to extend MapActivity,I can't Activity for example,

Framework Level,

**Activity** extends **CommonActivity** extends **MainActivity**

Here is my problem,

If i extends MapActivity instead of Activity it causes any problem or it has any drawbacks?

Thanks,
Nikhilreddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so there are any drawbacks of map activity because map activity extends Activity Class.

```
public abstract class MapActivity extends android.app.Activity
```

But You have to Run your application on a device or emulator that has Google Maps installed.